# How can I check if a Lucene IndexWriter instance is valid/open?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Sorry for the simple question, but there doesn't seem to be any obvious way. According to the documentation, it is recommended to keep a single instance of `IndexWriter` in memory that can be used again and again for updates, as opposed to opening and closing one for each change (which is much more costly).

However, the documentation also states that the `IndexWriter` should be closed if an exception occurs (e.g. `OutOfMemoryException`).

Therefore, I need some way to check if my instance of `IndexWriter` is valid or not, assuming it could be closed by some other operation.

I realize I will get an exception if I try to use it when it's closed, but rather than fail, I would like to check to see if I need to create a new `IndexWriter` before I need it so no failure occurs.

It seems to me a simple `IsOpen` property/method would be such an obvious addition.

**Thoughts:**

I suppose that if I could ensure that my class is the only thing capable of closing the `IndexWriter`, I could simply set it to `null` when it was closed and just check to make sure it's not `null` whenever I go to use it, however this would not handle cases where the `IndexWriter` closes itself (if such a case is possible now or in the future).

Another thought is that I could wrap an attempt to use it in a try/catch block and use the exception to indicate that it needs to be reopened, but this doesn't seem very efficient/elegant. What method would I use to test the validity of the `IndexWriter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you get an out of memory exception (or any kind of exception, really), that's potentially a big problem. The changes you were trying to write probably won't get written, and your index may even be corrupt, depending on when/how the exception occurred.

So an `IndexWriter` being in a faulted state is an exceptional circumstance, and I would say it certainly warrants using exceptions, i.e. try/catch.

(I don't think your catch would be "reopen the writer." Depending on the exception, you might need to reindex stuff, possibly from scratch. Certainly you shouldn't expect to get exceptions in your writer as a regular occurrence.)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the `IndexWriter` would throw an `AlreadyClosedException` (see [ensureOpen](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_9_2/api/all/index.html)), if it is closed on access. So you could handle that in case the `IndexWriter` is not `null`.

HTH